# Removing Mirrored Pairs from SQL Join

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a table with 2 fields (name, interest) and I want to find all pairs that have the same interest, with all duplicates and mirrored pairs removed.

I am able to find all pairs and remove duplicates with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT P1.name AS name1, P2.name AS name2, P1.interest 
FROM Table AS P1, Table AS P2
WHERE P1.interest = P2.interest AND P1.name <> P2.name;
```

But I am not sure how to remove mirrored pairs, ie:

`"wil","ben","databases"`

`"ben","wil","databases"`

I tried to make the above statement a view called Matches and attempted the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Matches
WHERE name2 <> (select name1 from Matches);
```

But it does not remove all mirrored pairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you do not care which pair ends up sticking around (ben,will) vs (will, ben), then my preferred solution is to do the following:

```
DELETE p2 
FROM Pairs p1 
INNER JOIN Pairs p2 
    on p1.Name1 = p2.Name2 
    and p1.Name2 = p2.Name1 
    and p1.Interest = p2.Interest
    -- match only one of the two pairs
    and p1.Name1 > p1.Name2
```

By virtue of the fact that you would never have Name1 and Name2 equal, there must always be one pair where the first member is less than the second member.  Using that relationship, we can delete the duplicate.

This is especially trivial if you have a surrogate key for the relationship, as then the requirement for Name1 and Name2 to be unequal goes away.

**Edit:** if you don't want to remove them from the table, but just from the results of a specific query, use the same pattern with `SELECT` rather than `DELETE`.

Comment: @wilco, No benefit to using an ANSII join vs the Cartesian product from a performance or even query-plan.  The difference is in maintainability, but it is very subjective.  See http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618.  As far as performance is concerned, it would depend upon the RDBMS you are using.  Some may execute that as a subquery, once per row in `N1` rather than materializing a view and doing a map against that.

Comment: @wilco, to put some numbers to Subquery vs Join, check out this url: http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/06/correlated-sub-queries-for-good-or-evil.html which discusses the implications for SQL Server specifically and outlines the dangers with correlated sub queries.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch! I really appreciate the extra info

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and figure out studying the first answer that the query below will do the trick

```
SELECT P1.name AS name1,P2.name AS name2,P1.interest 
FROM Table AS P1,Table AS P2
WHERE P1.interest=P2.interest AND P1.name>P2.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have table `Name` with tuples:

```
 F1  F2           
Jon Smith          
Smith Jon
```

then to remove this pair we can make query like this:

```
SELECT n1.F1, n1.F2         
FROM Name n1            
WHERE n1.F1 > (SELECT n2.F1  
                  FROM Name n2  
                  WHERE n1.F1=n2.F2)
```

So Instead of using `<>` in

```
(SELECT * FROM Matches
WHERE name2 **<>** (select name1 from Matches);)
```

use `>` or `<` operator and It should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! That works great! Do you happen to know the relational algebra equivalent of this? I am no trying to fully understand the problem.

Comment: I dont know right now, but I will try to make one. I am also thinking to solve it in some different way. Please update if you find some other solution.