# Exclude same pairs from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has two columns in it:

```
primId   column1   column2
1         98        62
2         62        98
3         3         105
4         105       3
5         11        4
```

I need to get second row, fourth row, fifth row.
if 98,62 has appeared once then 62,98 cannot appear (if possible I need latest value).
I have taken help from this link [Removing Mirrored Pairs from SQL Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104744/removing-mirrored-pairs-from-sql-join), but got no luck.
These values are not related to each other in greater or lesser.
Please let me know how I can get this result.
Is this possible with Sql query.
Thanks

Comment: do you have to delete those rows? or just `select` them?

Comment: just select them

Comment: Latest value, how? Do you have an ID column or timestamp column as well?

Comment: yes there is a primary Auto increment id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
select  t1.*
from    yourTable t1
left join
        yourTable t2
on      t1.column1 = t2.column2 and
        t1.column2 = t2.column1
where   t2.column1 is null or
        t1.column1 > t1.column2
```

The mirrored rows will be joined, and you will only take them once due to the second `where` condition, and the rows that are not mirrored will not be joined, so you'll get them with the first `where` condition.

**Edit**

To have the last couple returned, you can use this approach instead

```
select  t1.*
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  max(primId) as primId,
                    case when column1 > column2 then column2 else column1 end c1,
                    case when column1 < column2 then column2 else column1 end c2
            from    yourTable
            group by case when column1 > column2 then column2 else column1 end,
                     case when column1 < column2 then column2 else column1 end
        ) t2
on      t1.primId = t2.primId
```

The inner query will return the highest `primId` for each couple, regardless of the order. Joining it with the source table, you use it as a filter.

You can see it working [here](http://rextester.com/MMYODC13288)

Comment: This is giving more than desired rows.

Comment: @user1578460 . . . That is because the logic is not correct.  This brings every row where `column1 > column2`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(column1, column2) AS column1,
                GREATEST(column1, column2) AS column2
FROM mytable
```

**Note:** The above query works provided the field order is irrelevant to you. Otherwise you have to use a `JOIN` like @Stefano proposes.

Answer (score 0):

When it doesn't matter if the row in the result-set of the query exists in the table, you can use `least` and `greatest` so that one row per pair is retrieved.

```
select distinct least(column1,column2) as col1, greatest(column1,column2) as col2 
from tablename
```

If the row retrieved **has** to be present in the table, use the previous query and join it to the existing table.

```
select t.column1,t.column2
from tablename t
left join (select least(column1,column2) as col1, greatest(column1,column2) as col2 
           from tablename
           group by least(column1,column2), greatest(column1,column2)
           having count(*)>1
          ) x on x.col1=t.column1 and x.col2=t.column2
where x.col1 is null and x.col2 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that you keep the original pairs (so 4,1 would not be allowed as output), then the following should be very efficient:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.column1 <= t.column2
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.column1 > t.column2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.column1 = t.column2 and t2.column2 = t.column1);
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `t(column1, column2)`.